# Terence Tao uncountability of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

There is a small detail I would like to understand. In the proof presented by Tao below: I don't understand why do we have the following cancellation:

$\Sigma_{n < n_0 : n \in A} 10^{-n} - \Sigma_{n < n_0 : n \in B} 10^{-n}$ ?

I mean we could have elements $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n < n_0$ for which $n \in A - B$ or vice versa. [image]

Comment: Where is this from? I've never seen this proof, it seems quite interesting

Comment: Minor observation: This proof is essentially what you would do to prove base 10 decimal expansions are unique except for cases of an infinite tail of 9s. Since he only uses coefficients of zero and one, there are no messy details related to tails of 9s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Our definition of $n_0$ is such that it is the *least* $k$ such that $k$ is in set $A$ but not $B$ or vice versa. Thus, all $n$ below $n_0$ would appear in both sets, so we can just cancel them.

Comment: ...  in both sets or in neither ....

Comment: Yeah. That makes sense. Thanks.